# How to make the height of the Container returned by InViewNotifierList flexible

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

This is regarding the package [inview_notifier_list](https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list). t
I tried to modify the official example with the video auto-playing in a list when it comes into view (example 3). I however came across a small challenge.

In the official example, `InViewNotifierList` returns a `Container` with a fixed height.
I realized that when I don't give the container a height, nothing is shown on the screen and when I give the `Container` a very big height, say 800.0, the children begin to look ugly.

How can I approach a scenario where I don't want the container to have a fixed height, for example in a scenario where I want to return a column widget with a text, a video and a button as children and would like the height of the container to adjust itself automatically in relation to the length of the text, something like this:

```
class VideoList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InViewNotifierList(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      initialInViewIds: ['0'],
      isInViewPortCondition:
          (double deltaTop, double deltaBottom, double viewPortDimension) {
        return deltaTop < (0.5 * viewPortDimension) &&
            deltaBottom > (0.5 * viewPortDimension);
      },
      itemCount: 10,
      builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          //I would like to have a flexible height here
          height: 400,
          child: InViewNotifierWidget(
            id: '$index',
            builder: (BuildContext context, bool isInView, Widget? child) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text("Some long text from a database"),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: VideoWidget(
                        play: isInView,
                        url:
                            'https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/premium/video0392/large_watermarked/906_906-1044_preview.mp4'),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 40,
                    child: Text("Button"),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm going to need some eye bleach for that bracket formatting :(

Comment: Sorry about that ( 
I have reformatted, I believe it looks better now.

Comment: "I realized that when I don't give the container a height"
What if you remove that container?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using a `Column` as items of a vertically scrolling list. What's worse, you added `Expanded` inside the `Column` to tell it to "occupy all available space (be as tall as possible)",  but a vertically scrolling list (viewport) has infinite vertical space - that's a conflict and will throw an error for you.

Remove the `Expanded` should fix the problem. If you want to insert white spaces in a `Column` you can use something like `SizedBox(height: 200)`. If you have more complex needs, you should look into `SliverFillViewport` and `SliverFillRemaining` widgets. If you want to get total available space, try `LayoutBuilder` or `MediaQuery` widgets.